# Uma mesma variavel se repete várias vezes no while

Tags: php, while

No *while* as palavras estão aparecendo várias vezes, exemplo:

```
macarrão
macarrão
macarrão
macarrão
macarrão
macarrão
arroz
arroz
arroz
arroz
arroz
arroz
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
<?php
$usuario=$_SESSION['email'];

require_once 'Classes/ProjetosVO.php';
require_once 'Classes/ProjetosDAO.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');

$objBDProjeto=new ProjetosDAO();
$objProjeto= new ProjetosVO();

$rsProjeto= $objBDProjeto->ListarProjetos("1");

$sqlProjetos="select P.codigo_PROJETO, P.nome_PROJETO from projetos P, usuarios U, funcoes F where U.email_USUARIO like '$usuario' and U.email_USUARIO=F.emailUsuario_FUNCAO and U.email_USUARIO=P.responsavel_PROJETO and F.status_FUNCAO=1 ";

$rsProjeto= mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlProjetos) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

$tblProjeto=mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto);


?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb2dfeaa2c.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<center><h1 class="Titulo">Meus Projetos</h1></center>

&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php
    include 'FormCadastraProjeto.php';
?>
<?php
    while($tblProjeto==mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto)){

?>
<a href="Projeto.php?codProjeto=<?=$tblProjeto['codigo_PROJETO'];?>" >      <h1><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>

<?php
    echo $tblProjeto['nome_PROJETO'];
?>
</a>

<?php
  }

?>
```

Comment: 2 vezes? $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');

Answer (score 1):

Não sei direito a sua estrutura das tabelas, mas poderá resolver isto colocando um **`distinct`** depois do **`select`**:

```
$sqlProjetos="select DISTINCT P.codigo_PROJETO, P.nome_PROJETO from projetos P, usuarios U, funcoes F..."
```

Veja se funcionará assim.

Answer (score 0):

Oque vc esta comparando neste **while** ?. Dependendo poderia usar

```
foreach($tblProjeto as $tp){
?>
<a href="Projeto.php?codProjeto=<?=$tp['codigo_PROJETO'];?>" >      <h1><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu mysqli_fetch_array está repetido e colocado de modo errado no while. Veja o comentário sobre a linha do seu código abaixo:

```
...$rsProjeto= mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlProjetos) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

$tblProjeto=mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto);  // <<<--- Remova essa linha que está repetida com o while.

?>...
```

Depois arrume o seu while que está em forma de comparação com dois sinais de igual (==) do seguinte modo:

```
<?php
    while($tblProjeto==mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto)){

?>
```

Para:

```
<?php
    while($tblProjeto = mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

?>
```

Ainda não da pra saber o porque da repetição, mas pode ser por causa dessas duas linhas, por além de repetir as duas linhas, e fazer um modo de comparação no while, se você não colocar modo de retorno do array o php vai retornar todos os modos. O que pode causar repetição. É um pouco complicado de explicar. Mas da pra você fazer um teste depois com var_dump no seu mysqli_fetch_array, e ver o que ele retorna.

Mas em fim, tenta fazer essas alterações, e me diz se ajudou. Caso continue com a repetição ou de algum erro, me avise.